# How to search for questions and answers between two users?

Tags: support, search

I am searching for the questions posted by me (user:139150) that were answered by another user.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A139150

His ID is: 55159

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A55159

There does not seem to be any way to search for posts where both the users are involved.

Comment: I'd think the only way would be the data explorer, but someone prove me wrong. ;)

Comment: Bala, that did not work.

Comment: Google advanced search maybe somewhat helpful: [link](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=shantanuo+Quassnoi&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com&as_occt=body&safe=images&tbs=&as_filetype=&as_rights=#as_qdr=all&lr=&q=allintext:+shantanuo+Quassnoi+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com)

Comment: @BartoszKP nice idea

Comment: Is this the [data explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/144655/question-and-answer-user) you are looking for?

Comment: @rene Use the [`[Post Link]`](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/144657/178319/question-and-answer-user) alias name.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I guess you want me to do something different but I've no  clue what you could possibly mean....

Comment: Site search returns matches **per post**, and as each post only has *one author* you cannot do this with the site search. You'll have to use other means, such as the data explorer or Google. Technically, it should be possible to add an index for answers to include the question author, but the usecase is, I suspect, rather specialized and rare enough not to warrant the additional dev time and space requirements.

Comment: @rene [`[Post Link]`](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/144657/178319/question-and-answer-user) is a link. :)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn got it! didn't know [that](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/144655/178329/question-and-answer-user)

Answer (score 5):

You can run [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for such process  explained as follows:

1. Go to [Stack Exchange Data Explorer This Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/144655/question-and-answer-user).
2. You can set appropriate site as shown below:
   [image]
3. Then click on fork query and change userid (questioner & answerer respectively) as shown below:

   [image]
4. Then click on Run Query button:

   [image]

And you will get result link.

Comment: site data.stackexchange.com does not seem to be working!